# How to add new(customized) Theme colors to Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Can anybody please help me with adding new(customized) theme colors to a ppt presentation. By Theme colors I mean, the color pallette that shows up in the little popup when we click on **Shape Fill**, **Shape Outline** buttons in PPT.

Thanks in advance,
Sri.

Answer (score 0):

Echo Swinford has a tutorial on adding colors manually and a link to an add-in that does the job.

http://echosvoice.com/tutorials-2/2010-2/powerpoint-2010-custom-colors/

It involves modifying one of the XML files that make up a PPTX/etc. file.