# Adding customized colors to POTX file

Tags: powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I know there already is an answer to the question here:

[How to add new(customized) Theme colors to Powerpoint using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173954/how-to-add-newcustomized-theme-colors-to-powerpoint-using-vba)

But it didn't work. And as I'm not allowed to comment there (not enough reputation) I'm sorry for opening up a new question. (Dear admins - this isn't really clever in my opinion. Now we have two threads on the same thing, just because I'm not allowed to comment.)

Back to topic:

http://echosvoice.com/wp-content/uploads/pptfiles/customcolors.pdf

I followed the instructions of Echo, recommended in the other thread, but it didn't work. I have ppt2010 and tried with a THMX, a POTX and a PPTX. It's always the same. I rename the file by adding a .zip - I extract the ZIP - I copy Echo's example code and paste it right before /a:theme in theme1.xml file - I save it - I zip the whole folder - I delete the ZIP Extension - and it's corrupt. When I doubleclick, PPT opens without a slide. When I got to "open" and choose the template, I get an error message. "Repair" doesn't help. - What am I doing wrong?

(Somewhere else I read, I have to add this to every theme-file, but it doesn't make a difference)

Comment: Update: My problem seems to have to do with unzipping or zipping. I tested this right now: I took a file, added .zip, extracted it, zipped it again and deleted the extension. Nothing inbetween, no work on the theme.xml. And that was enough to corrupt the file. Any idea what I can do about it?

Comment: If you are just looking for a solution then take a look at this free add-in - http://www.skphub.com/swatch.htm

Comment: Thank you, Shyam, your add-in is wonderful and I'm sure, one day it's going to help me save time, but in this special case I need to add more than 12 colors.

Answer (score 0):

Be kind to yourself.  Use 7-zip (free) to open the PPTX (it can open them directly w/o having to rename them, and won't corrupt the files).

Alternatively, rename the file to zip, doubleclick to open the zip in Windows Explorer, drag any file you need to edit to the desktop, edit it there, drag it back into the still-open zip, then close the zip.

Comment: Thank you, Steve. I've downloaded 7-zip and opening was as easy as you said, but how can I get the changed back into a PPTX file? Creating a 7z file and renaming it caused similar problems and saving the folder as a PPTX seems to be impossible. Or let's say: I haven't found a way to do so. (I always expect, the problem is me ... ;)

Comment: Here, I rightclick the PPTX, choose 7-Zip | Open Archive from the popup menu.  I have 7-Zip set to launch Notepad+ when I doubleclick one of the XML files within the archive/PPTX.  I do the editing there, save and when 7-Zip asks if I want to update the archive with the changed file, say yes.  Then simply click the upper-right X box to close the archive.  Also, make sure to use a plain text editor, not Word or some other program that doesnt' save pure text.

Comment: After two month of high workload I'm coming back to this, because I want to learn ...

Comment: 1. I open 7z
2. I rightclick my pptx and choose 7zip - Open - 7z (See here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5tul57xzxwwg4cn/Shot-for-Steve01.png?dl=0)
3. I get this error message: https://www.dropbox.com/s/erjcbf76ymcjh42/Shot-for-Steve02.png?dl=0
It says: The file can't be opened as an Archive
So, obviously I didn't get you right. Other try:
1. I open 7z
2. I select my PPTX and say "unzip"
3. I follow Echo's instructions to change the theme.XML (with plain text editor)
4. I don't know how to put the parts together into a pptx

Comment: Choose the other "Offnen" option, the one at the top of the list.

Comment: Ok, I do that and find my way to themes.XML. I choose "edit", which is the only option to edit in the editor. I do my edits and save. I close it. I'm asked if I want the changes to be taken into the archive. I agree. I open my PPTX and get the mesage, that something is changed and I can choose between repairing (which makes some in the master, but still not adds my additional color) and just close it again. :-(

Comment: It sounds as though you may have edited the file incorrectly.  If the XML isn't valid, you'll get that sort of message from PPT.

Comment: Well all I Do ist adding
<a:custClrLst>
<a:custClr name=”Dark Blue”>
<a:srgbClr val=”1F497D” />
</a:custClr>
</a:custClrLst>
in front of </a:theme>
And it makes no difference, whether I do it in theme 1 only, or in all.

Comment: Make sure you're using straight quotes " " instead of true open/close quote marks.  Also, try applying a different theme to the presentation first; it seems if you make the edits to the default theme, PPT will accept the file but won't show the Custom colors.

Comment: It has been the quotes! In fact in the editor I couldn't see a difference between those copied from Echo's PDF and new straight ones, but to be sure I replaced them - and that was it! Steve, I believe, nobody knows PowerPoint as good as you. Thank you so much for your help and your patience!

Comment: BINGO!  And Echo's a friend ... I'll let her know she needs to change the quotes in the PDF document.

Comment: It's ridiculous. Now it's the first time I have to do this for business (so this time it is not for learning purposes) and it's not working any way. I tried Shilam's tool first and it is creating a Color Theme but not showing the five additional custom colors I added. Then I tried to do it Echo's way (and did not forget to change the quotes!), but it always corrupts the file. I have no idea, what is going on here, as both ways worked when we left this thread 6 months ago.

Comment: His name is Shyam, sorry. ;-)

Comment: Finally I found my mistake and was able to make it work with Echo's method. It's really heavy, one little typing mistake destroys not only one color but the whole document.
Well, and I still have no explanation, why Shyam's tool isn't showing the custom colors.